# Fullcalendar v5 : how to display current day in diffrent background color

Tags: html, css, angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm using fullcalendar v5 , angular .
And I want to know how to change the background color of current day , week view (slot duration 12h)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

for fullcalendar week view change this in calendar css :

```
.fc-day-today {
    background-color: red !important;
  }
```

and for fullcalendar week view ***slot 12h display*** :

```
.fc-slot-today {
    background-color: red !important;
 }
```